# I'm creating a table and am coloring the text green or red depending of + or - value, is there a way I can remove the sign from the number

Tags: django, django-templates, unsigned, django-template-filters

I am trying to remove the '- 'sign from my number when it displays in html because I don't need it any more as I have color coded the text instead. Is this possible and if so how could I remove the - sign if there is one ?

Table loop below

```
{% for sale in page_obj %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{sale.transaction.currency}}</td>
                <td>{{sale.amount_sold}}</td>
                <td>{{sale.amount_per_coin_sold}}</td>
                <td>{{sale.total_price_sold}}</td>
                <td>{{sale.transaction.amount_per_coin}}</td>
                <td>{{sale.date_sold|date:"j N Y"}}</td>
                {% if sale.profit_loss < 0 %}
                    <td style = "color:red">{{ sale.profit_loss }}</td>
                {% else %}
                <td style = "color:green">{{ sale.profit_loss }}</td>
                {% endif %}  
                {% if sale.profit_loss_percent < 0 %}
                <td style = "color:red">{{sale.profit_loss_percent}}</td>
                {% else %}
                <td style = "color:green">{{sale.profit_loss_percent}}</td>
                {% endif %}
                 <td><a href="{% url 'sale-detail' sale.id %}">View</a></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Connum he's asking for a django template solution, not a js solution.

Comment: @Connum no, this isn't handlebars, this is Django template syntax, similar to Liquid templates or Jinja2. They do not support writing expressions (for reasons the language authors have expressed very clearly) and they definitely don't support javascript expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new function inside your model like:

```
def get_absolute_profit_loss(self):
    return abs(self.profit_loss)
```

And then inside the template you can do this:

```
{% if sale.profit_loss < 0 %}
     <td style = "color:red">{{ sale.get_absolute_profit_loss }}</td>
{% else %}
     <td style = "color:green">{{ sale.profit_loss }}</td>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben. but i am getting this error when i implement this. do you have any idea why?

Comment: I spot the error there was() after profit_loss in the function

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom template filter which calls `abs()`.

```
@register.filter
def absolute(val):
    return abs(val)
```

And use it:

```
{% load my_template_tags %}
{% if sale.profit_loss < 0 %}
    <td style = "color:red">{{ sale.profit_loss|absolute }}</td>
{% else %}
```

Comment: Thanks @ Daniel, Where would i put the @register.filter method

Answer (score 0):

You can [write a filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) to get the absolute value.

```
@register.filter
def abs(value):
    '''
    Returns the absolute value of a number without the sign
    '''
    return abs(value)
```

Then in your template you can apply the filter to your value

```
{{ sale.profit_loss|abs }}
```

If you don't want to write your own filter, the [django-mathfilters](https://pypi.org/project/django-mathfilters/0.1.2/) module has an `abs` filter in it already.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom filter as described in other answers, or alternatively you could add methods to your model, E.g.

```
def absolute_profit_loss(self):
    return abs(self.profit_loss())
```